# Interpreting exim log files after parsing

Tags: exim, hadoop

I'm parsing exim log files and, due to my processing method, lose the original order of *all* entries in this file.  I rebuild the transactions by their transaction ID (i.e. `1OfiYX-0000Ev-7k`) but still don't have a way to determine the original order.

The `<=` , `=>` , `==` , `**` characters' original order matter, right?  Is there a way to rebuild the order without any additional information?

Αντίο

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer, limited solely to the symbols you ask about, is that `<=` is always going to come before each of the other symbols you list, and a message's `Completed` line will come after all of those symbols.  However, each of the other symbols `==`, `=>`, `**`, can appear in any order between `<=` and `Completed`.

One thing to keep in mind is that a message can have multiple recipients, and each of those recipients can be deferred (`==`), so the order of those symbols matters **for each recipient of the message**

So, every message should have exactly one `<=` when the message is accepted by the local server

Every message should have exactly one `Completed` line indicating that the local server is done with the message

Between those:

Each message:recipient will have exactly one of `**` (failure) or `=>` (delivered).  It will be the last entry for that specific message:recipient.

Each message:recipient may have one or more `==` (deferred) lines.  If a message:recipient has a `==` log line, it will occur before that message:recipient's `=>` or `**` line.

The order of different recipients in a given message only matters if you think it matters, most likely.

Comment: +1. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Exim is shipped with tools to help with logfile analysis.  In particular, exigrep may be of interest, as it can search for a pattern in a line and then show *all* the log-lines for that message, including those which came before the match-line.

Exim is shipped with documentation, "The Exim Specification"; at the very least, you should have a file called "spec.txt", if not .pdf or other variant; this is also online at http://www.exim.org/; you might find "49. Log files", documenting the precise format of the log-files, and "50. Exim utilities" to be useful.

Each log-line has a timestamp; group by exim message-id and then sort by timestamp and you have the original order back.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the matter as they indicate the direction of the message flow. You need to improve your processing method not to reorder your entries.

Comment: *Is there a way to rebuild the order without any additional information?*

Comment: Yes there could be it depends on how hadoop has split the lines. because each line has the ID you should be able to reassemble the message.

Comment: So here is my next finding.  1) I sent a message FROM the server. 2) I sent a message TO the server.  Both had the same structure. The first log entry *always* contained the `<=` while the second entry contained the others `=>`, `==`, etc.  Based on the ID, why can't I just rebuild the message so the `<=` always is the first line?  Am I misunderstanding something?  Based on this experiment, I want to say order *doesn't* matter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using one of the available log file parsers, e.g. [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) or [sawmill](http://www.sawmill.net/formats/exim.html).